# Network contagion

Tags: probability, graph-theory, network

Suppose I have an undirected, unweighted network in which some node, $i$, is infected.  This (and any) infected node has probability $p$ of infecting adjacent nodes. Is there a closed form expression of the probability that an arbitrary node $j$ becomes infected?  Any references would be much appreciated!

My thought is that this should be somehow related to the resistance distance between the nodes.

EDIT: So after some simulations there doesn't appear to be much relationship with resistance distance.  I think this is because resistance can be understood as a situation where `voltage' doesn't change as additional paths are added.  Here however, adding more connections to the infected source node (in some sense) increases the outward flow of contagion (a voltage analog)

EDIT 2:  Let me be more clear about the process I have in mind.  Take a connected undirected graph,$G$, as given.  Some node, $i$, starts out as infected.  In period 1, each node adjacent to $i$ has probability, $p$, of becoming infected.  In subsequent periods, for each newly infected node, each of its uninfected neighbors has probability $p$ of becoming newly infected for the next period.  Can we characterize the probability that an arbitrary node, $j$, becomes infected after infinitely many periods?

Comment: Do you make any hypothesis on your network? (you basically have to, since the problem is very general) Have you started by the page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epidemic_model?

Comment: So I had sort of seen that before.  Taking a closer look now I think the main difference is that I'm interested in the case where each individual is only able to transmit to a certain group of susceptible neighbors.  Somewhat related to the lattice version of SIR perhaps, but still different.

What sort of hypotheses might help?  I'd be willing to assume the graph is connected would other conditions be useful?

I'm aware of the random walk characterization of resistance distance and was hoping a similar `nice' distance measure might exist for this contagion process.

Comment: Well, consider what happens if the graph is complete, edgeless, a path... In general, either you assume the graph to have a certain form, or you assume it comes from a given random graph model. In the second case the most general result I know of is the paper "A weighted configuration model and inhomogeneous epidemics".

Comment: So for all of those types of graphs you find infection probability is $p^{R(i,j)}$ where R is effective resistance between the source $i$ and another node $j$. It feels like a general characterization should be possible.

Comment: Well, the probability $p^{R(i,j)}$ is the probability that $i$ infects $j$ by definition... But if you look at the probability that an _arbitrary_ node is infected, it is very different in the case of a path or a clique. This probability depends strongly on the "resistance" and on the "network topology".

Comment: So this works for any acyclic graph.  However, I agree that the network topology has important effects when things get more complicated.  For instance (assuming iid infections which I should have said), a triangle graph with i-j-k-i  and source $i$ would have $Pr(k~infected)=Pr(j ~infected)=p +(1-p)p^2=p(1+p-p^2)$  while the $R(i,k)=R(i,j)=(1+\tfrac{1}{2})^{-1}=\tfrac{2}{3}$.  So here of course the relation between these concepts is unclear if there is one at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36126/discussion-between-graffitics-and-kevin).